# MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException:“Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.”

Tags: sql-server

I am using Visual Studio 2019 to build a form application, and I have also built a database on SQL Server 2018. Connecting to the database on VS tests the connection successfully.
But the problem came, when I clicked the button control, I got the following exception`String connetStr = "Data Source=DESKTOP-T4C1MK6;Initial Catalog=Company;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=123456";
            MySqlConnection sqlconnect = new MySqlConnection(connetStr);
            sqlconnect.Open();`

[image: The error]

[image: The code]

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MySQL? You seem to have built a database on SQL Server 2018 but you are using MySqlConnection object.

Comment: You said you using SQL Server and your connection is using MySql, is that correct?

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18, I could not log in before running Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18, and later I installed SQL2019-SSEI-Dev.exe

Comment: So, can you open up SQL Server Management Studio and log on to your SQL Server with `sa` user and it's password?

Comment: Remove `MySqlConnection sqlconnect = new MySqlConnection(connetStr);`. Instead of that use `SqlConnection sqlconnect = new SqlConnection(connetStr);`. Up on top of your C# code, type `using System.Data.SqlClient;`. Try running your code and see if the error exists.

Comment: I used it for the first time, the problem has been solved, thank you for your reminder

Comment: I'll add that as an answer below and you can accept the answer if you please to put closure to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are indeed using SQL Server and not MySQL. In order for you to correctly connect to SQL Server, do this:

At the top of the file, type:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Then, replace this line (because you aren't using MySQL database):

```
MySqlConnection sqlconnect = new MySqlConnection(connetStr);
```

with this line (because you are using SQL Server):

```
SqlConnection sqlconnect = new SqlConnection(connetStr);
```

You should then be able to connect to SQL Server just fine.